# Get Current Drive Letter Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

All I'm looking for is a way to get the current drive letter that I am currently running the powershell script from.

I know I can get the current path using `Get-Location` but is there a way to extract the drive letter without doing some kind of substring operation?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "drive letter that I am currently running the script from", the previous answer by @driis may not be appropriate. If you want the drive letter from the path to the script, this can differ from the current working directory that's returned with `Get-Location`. In these cases, start with strings or objects populated with data pulled from variables noted in [this question], and work from there. For example, once you've got a string with the path to the script (call it `$ScriptPath`) do: `(Get-Item $ScriptPath).PSDrive.Name`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you can get the drive letter without string operations:

```
(get-location).Drive.Name
```

Remember, that PowerShell seldom returns strings, but rich objects. You can always examine your further options from a result by using `get-member`.

Also note, that if you are not on the file system provider, the Name might not be a one-character string.

**Edit:**

As per x0n's comment below, here is a shorthand version:

```
$pwd.drive.name
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted and I figured it out about the same time you answered.  You still get credit thought, thanks!

Comment: This also works, using "pwd" but more in the manner originally specified. `(pwd).Drive.Name`.

Comment: When on a UNC path, this is null

Comment: Yes, when you are on a UNC path I'd argue there is no "Current Drive".